# Using Regex to capture phrase

Tags: python, regex

My question is regarding the following tweets:

```
Credit Suisse Trims Randgold Resources Limited (RRS) Target Price to GBX

JPMorgan Chase & Co Trims Occidental Petroleum Co (OXY) Target Price to
```

I want to remove *"Randgold Resources Limited (RRS)"* from the first tweet and *"Occidental Petroleum Co (OXY)"* from the second tweet using Regex.

I am working in Python and so far I have tried this without much luck:

```
Trims\s[\w\s.()]+(?=Target)
```

I want to capture the phrase *"Trims Target Price"* in both instances. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?<= Trims) .*?(?= Target )')      
result = re.sub(p, "", test_str)
```

`(?<= Trims) .*?(?= Target )` will match any text that is between `Trim` and `Target`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF4tP5/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=Trims )([A-Z][a-z]+ ){3}\([A-Z]{3}\)
```

[See it in action](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3DTrims%20)(%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%20)%7B3%7D%5C(%5BA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%5C)&test_string=Credit%20Suisse%20Trims%20Randgold%20Resources%20Limited%20(RRS)%20Target%20Price%20to%20GBX%0A%0AJPMorgan%20Chase%20%26%20Co%20Trims%20Occidental%20Petroleum%20Co%20(OXY)%20Target%20Price%20to%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

---

The idea is:

- `(?<=Trims )` - find a place preceded by `Trims` using [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` - a word starting with capital letter that continues with multiple lower case letters
- `([A-Z][a-z]+ ){3}` - three such words followed by space
- `\(` and `\)` - brackets have to be escaped, otherwise they have the meaning of capturing group
- `[A-Z]{3}` - three capital letters

Answer (score 0):

The `(?<=...) Lookbehind assertion, match if preceded` is missing for `Trims` word.

```
re.sub('(?<=Trims)\s[\w\s.()]+(?=Target)', ' ', text)
```